# android zoom in button only with webview

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I have a simple android webview app and I want to add zoom in button only,

I added the zoom in button in the graphical layout:

[image]

but how can I make it work in the java file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity, add an on click listener to your button that zooms in the webview:

```
findViewById(R.id.zoom_in_btn).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    webviewer.zoomIn();

                }
            });
```